# "Xpressive leak" fixed, but not understood

Tags: memory-leaks, xpressive

I know. Xpressive is (probably) not at fault here, but I've put a lot of effort into finding the memory leaks and I had to adapt the code layout to fix the haemorrhage.

Can someone explain to me why the change in layout fixed it? I don't see why the (correct/improved) use of "static const" fixes the leaks.

BTW, the leaks were occurring on a MIPs core, using boost version 1.49, and cross compiled with GCC 4.3.3.

Original "sieve" code:

```
// source.cpp
#include <boost/...

cregex token = keep(+set[ alnum|'!'|'%'|'_'|'*'|'+'|'.'|'\''|'`'|'~'|'-']);
cregex more  = ...

bool foo(const char * begin, const char * end, size_t& length, std::string& dest)
{
    mark_tag name_t(1);
    cregex regx = bos >>
        icase("name:") >>
        (name_t= token) >> eos;

    cmatch what;
    bool ok = regex_search( begin, end, what, regx );
    ...
    return ok;
}
```

Fixed "non-leaky" code:

```
// header.hpp
#include <boost/...

class Xpr {
public:
    static const cregex token;
    static const cregex more;
};

// source.cpp
#include "header.hpp"

const cregex Xpr::token = keep(+set[ alnum|'!'|'%'|'_'|'*'|'+'|'.'|'\''|'`'|'~'|'-']);
const cregex Xpr::more  = ...

bool foo(const char * begin, const char * end, size_t& length, std::string& dest)
{
    mark_tag name_t(1);
    static const cregex regx = bos >>
        icase("name:") >>
        (name_t= Xpr::token) >> eos;

    cmatch what;
    bool ok = regex_search( begin, end, what, regx );
    ...
    return ok;
}
```

The leaks seemed to be occurring upon every call of foo!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After writing the below response, I tried to reproduce your problem and was unable to. Here is the code I'm using.

```
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>
using namespace boost;
using namespace xpressive;

cregex token = keep(+set[ alnum|'!'|'%'|'_'|'*'|'+'|'.'|'\''|'`'|'~'|'-']);
//cregex more  = ...

bool foo(const char * begin, const char * end)
{
    mark_tag name_t(1);
    cregex regx = bos >>
        icase("name:") >>
        (name_t= token) >> eos;

    cmatch what;
    bool ok = regex_search( begin, end, what, regx );
    //...
    return ok;
}

int main()
{
    char const buf[] = "name:value";
    while(true)
        foo(buf, buf + sizeof(buf) - 1);
}
```

This code doesn't leak. Is it possible you're using an earlier version of xpressive? Could you post a complete, self-contained example so I can investigate? Even better, file a bug and attach the code there. Thanks,

Eric

-----Begin Original Response-----

I suspect that you're running afoul of xpressive's [cycle tracking code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/xpressive/appendices.html#boost_xpressive.appendices.appendix_5__implementation_notes.cycle_collection_with___tracking_ptr___). See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.tips_n_tricks.create_grammars_on_a_single_thread) for a warning against nesting global regex objects in function-local ones. I think what's happening is that, in order to prevent dangling references, the function-local `regx` must hold a reference to `token`, and `token` must hold a (weak) reference back to `regx`. What is growing is `token`'s map of weak references. This isn't a leak in the strict technical sense, since the memory will get reclaimed when `token` gets destroyed. But it's obviously not ideal.

I fixed a similar "leak" in xpressive a while back by adding an opportunistic purge of the map to clear out weak references to expired regexes. I have to look into why it's not happening in this case. Please file a bug [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/). Thanks.

In the mean time, your fix is plenty good. Declaring the function-local `regx` static means it will only get constructed once, so `token`'s weak-reference map will never grow beyond size 1.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. My employer might not be overly impressed if I were to post the real code, sorry.
After further testing, it was found the even the use of static const within the function "foo" wasn't enough stem the leak entirely.
But I'm not seeing any leaks from the Xpr class static const members (yet).
My suspicions are heading towards some "funnies" in the MIPS version of GCC. I too **can't** reproduce "off target"